# divide screen into equal parts with overflow

Tags: css

I recently made a website where I needed 6 columns with the y overflow visible. I couldn't make a clean 6 divisions. The width needed to be wider to adjust for the 6 scrollbars and a bit of padding.

Is there a better way than my attempt?

```
<div class="col">

  <div class="section">
    Content that overflows this section. 

  </div>

</div>

    .col {

    width: 15.2%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.section {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;


}
```

It's very sloppy and the columns don't reach the far right edge.

I don't know jquery well enough to attempt but will like take any advice.

******** *I worked it out, so silly. You need to use % for everything including padding. Duh* ********* Sorry for wasting anyones time!

Comment: Try using a CSS grid framework like http://960.gs/ it will take all the hard work out of creating layouts.

Comment: That link will give you a grid design based on a fixed width layout (mainly 960px). I don't think it will be very useful on a variable width design as the op has designed. Using `%` will definitely solve the problems but sometimes the calculated value from `%` can be slightly off depending on the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it is better to set padding for the inner div `.section`, so there will be no need to adjust `.col` width.

Try this HTML code:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="section">
        Content that overflows this section. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="section">
        Content that overflows this section. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="section">
        Content that overflows this section. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="section">
        Content that overflows this section. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="section">
        Content that overflows this section. 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="section">
        Content that overflows this section. 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this  CSS:

```
#grid {
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.col {
    width: 16.6%;
    float: left;
}

.section {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-left: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}​
```

Please note that `#grid { margin-left: -15px; }` will help you get rid of unnecessary white space before first column

take a look at [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsMf9/2/)

Comment: Thats a much better way of achieving what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have been looking high and low for this snippet.. A big THANK YOU!